# Arduino BTSerial.available causing not to connect

Tags: c++, python-3.x, arduino, serial-port, software-serial

I am trying to send the contents of a file `test.txt` from a SD card on an Arduino Nano to my computer via Bluetooth using a HC-06 module. Below is my Arduino sketch and python code that I'm to send and receive respectively.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <SD.h>

const byte rxPin = 9;
const byte txPin = 8;
SoftwareSerial BTSerial(rxPin, txPin);
File myFile;

void setup() {
  pinMode(rxPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(txPin, OUTPUT);
  BTSerial.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);

  if (!SD.begin(4)){
    Serial.println("Init Failed");
    while(1);
  } else {
    Serial.println("Init Complete");
  }
}

void loop() {
  while (BTSerial.available() > 0) {
    Serial.println("connected...");
    myFile = SD.open("test.txt");
    if (myFile) {
      Serial.println("test.txt:");
      while (myFile.available()) {
        BTSerial.write(myFile.read());
      }
      BTSerial.write("\n");
      myFile.close();
    }
    else {
      Serial.println("error opening test.txt");
    }
  }
}
```

```
#Python 3.12 on windows
import serial

s = serial.Serial('COM5', 9600, timeout=10)
print("connected")
data=s.read_until()

print(data)
```

The arduino sketch normally just constantly send the data through the bluetooth serial, but this isn't really ideal, so I added the `while (BTSerial.available() >0)` loop and now it doesn't connect at all. Any ideas what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

from what I see the problem might be caused by the style of connecting. If I understand it correctly, the only thing you do on the PC side is opening a COM5 and **waiting for data**. On the board side you open serial communication and then **waiting for data**.

I'm not familiar with python or arduino API but since it's bluetooth the PC can't connect to the board because each device is waiting for something that'll never arrive.

I assume the board is supposed to be server device and the PC is supposed to be client device. To connect these two, from the start the:

- Board should be advertising some data (there should be some function like `advertisingStart` in the API I believe)
- PC should be scanning for the advertising data (I would start by checking if you can see the board in windows bluetooth devices - the win api for bluetooth might be little bit too much to only test the connection)

To simplify that, the board should offer it's services (aka advertise data) and the PC should recieve the offers and decide whether to accept or reject the services (aka scanning).

I would start by finding some example (I believe there'll be many since it's arduino) to find out how it works (to be honest it's quite hard to understand the original documentation even if you're already working with bluetooth). And start by checking the board in windows bluetooth devices so you don't have to write whole bluetooth console.

Hope it was useful.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In the long run, I decided ChatGPT would be easier since this is just a small project. I think I understand what happening there. Again, thank you for your answer.